# Is this a good enough abstraction or I can do better?

Tags: java, oop, jpa-2.0, ooad

Requirement: Requirement is to **pull** (execute()) a set of data sources. The pulls are are **Ordered**, can be **grouped** into small sub groups.

Design: Each pull is abstracted as a Step. A subgroup is represented as a WaterFallStep because the pull of each of the data source in a group is conditional and follows waterfall model i.e. if 1st data source pull in the group is successful then I' break out of the group.

Questions

1. Is this a good enough abstraction or i can do better?
2. How to represent this in JPA 2? I know we can use descriminators to map inheritance but my main concern is the 1-to-many relationship between WaterFallStep-to-BasicStep

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: any more inputs or suggestions pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should use a composite pattern here. I'd say that each step should handle reference to a collection of steps. If you want yo can move this collection to your WaterfallStep but it still should be a collection of Steps, not BasicSteps and not AbstractSteps.

Concerning JPA you should use OneToMany annotation. There are a lot of examples of usage of this annotation.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I started from composite pattern ;-). But there are certain "behaviors" that are not applicable to the leafs for e.g the waterfall behavior and keeping in mind the liskov substitution principle i need to resort to this design. let me know if I am overthinking ;-)